# django mongo engine - DatabaseError: Unknown option auto_start_request

Tags: python, django, mongodb

After going into the django shell and creating the following entry:

```
from blinks.models import *
q=Questions(
     questions='What is science?',
     tags=['science','psychology']
)
```

i am not able to use

```
q.save()
```

i am getting the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 548, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 668, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1675, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 592, in execute_sql
    key = self.insert(to_insert, return_id=return_id)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 84, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 387, in insert
    collection = self.get_collection()
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 296, in get_collection
    return self.connection.get_collection(self.query.get_meta().db_table)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 196, in get_collection
    collection = self.collection_class(self.database, name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 204, in __getattr__
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 261, in _connect
    self.connection = connection_class(**conn_options)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 322, in __init__
    username, password, dbase, opts)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/client_options.py", line 108, in __init__
    options = dict([validate(opt, val) for opt, val in iteritems(options)])
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 425, in validate
    value = validator(option, value)
  File "/Users/sunilkumar/blink2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 100, in raise_config_error
    raise ConfigurationError("Unknown option %s" % (key,))
DatabaseError: Unknown option auto_start_request
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/blink/
       - blink
             - __init__.py
             - settings.py
             - urls.py
             - wsgi.py
       - blinks (app folder)
             - __init__.py
             - models.py
             - views.py
             - tests.py
       - manage.py
```

The versions used are:

```
Python 2.7.5+
Django-1.5.11-py2.7
pymongo-3.0.1-py2.7
django_mongodb_engine-0.5.2-py2.7
djangotoolbox-1.6.2-py2.7
```

Is there anything i am missing?

Can somebody please help me on what the problem is? i am new to django and mongodb. I am not able to find the solution anywhere.

Comment: Can some one please help me? It is urgent...Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to downgrade the pymongo-3.0.1 to pymongo 2.7 which solved the issue. This error is because of the fact that most of the keywords has been changed or deprecated in pymongo-3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

Choose an auto-generated password instead of your password.
That worked for me